# Is the infinity function continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, almost-everywhere

Define the function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}\cup\{\infty\}$ as $f(x) = \infty$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Is this function continuous?

Intuitively it seems like it is, but I cannot prove this function is continuous in the usual $\varepsilon-\delta$ way because the difference $|f(x)-f(y)|$ is undefined for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$.

This problem came up when I was trying to determine if a continuous function $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}\cup\{-\infty\}\cup\{\infty\}$ must be finite a.e. Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: Well, it is a *constant* function...I can't think of any topology you can put on those spaces that will make that function dicontinuous.

Comment: @DonAntonio but how can you define a neighborhood of $\infty$ that does not contain just $\infty$ itself?

Comment: @bartgol It ll depends on the topology on $\;\Bbb R\cup\{\infty\}\;$ . Perhaps it is the one point compactification (Alexandroff) of the real line...? The OP has to tell us.

Comment: Notice that $\infty - \infty$ is not defined and the usual topology on $\mathbb R \cup \{\pm\infty\}$ does not involve a metric. Although it is metrizable, no closed form metric is know. So if you want talk about continuity, you need some different setting.

Comment: @DonAntonio I do not know much about topology, and was asking this question with the usual topology in mind.

Comment: The usual topology is the Euclidean distance topology, i.e. the one that uses open intervals as a basis for open sets. The problem then is: What is the distance between a finite $x$, and the special point $\infty$?

Comment: Then with the usual euclidean distance it is not possible to prove whether $f(x)=\infty$ is continuous?

Comment: @DonAntonio Indeed, *any* constant function between topological spaces is continuous, regardless of the topologies involved; see my answer.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Of course. I only wanted to stress the importance of taking some topology on the extended line. What you did is the easiest, or perhaps, the "most" natural way to do: the Alexandroff one-point compactification, which renders the extended line Hausdorff and nice. You though could have also chose the line with two origins, which is not even Hausdorff.

Comment: @user251257: Regarding "Although it is metrizable, no closed form metric is know[n]", I know three ways of explicitly defining a metric for the two-point compactification of the reals. One way is to let $d(x,y) = |g(x) - g(y)|,$ where $g:{\mathbb R} \cup \{-\infty,+\infty\} \rightarrow [0,\infty)$ by $g(-\infty) = -\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $g(x) = \arctan x$ if $x \in {\mathbb R}$ and $g(+\infty) = \frac{\pi}{2}.$

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro ah my bad. I meant as extension to the Euclidean distance. Sorry

Comment: @möbius: To clear it up: In your definition of $f$, what exactly do you mean when you write $\infty$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is indeed continuous, no matter what topology we put on either space: any constant map between two topological spaces is always continuous.

*Recall that in the context of topology, a map $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is continuous if $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$ whenever $U$ is open in $Y$. Well, in any topological space, both $\emptyset$ and the whole space are open by definition. Now if $f: X\rightarrow Y$ is constant, then the preimage of **any** set, open in $Y$ or not, is either $\emptyset$ or $X$; so $f$ is continuous.*

---

It is true that the usual metric on $\mathbb{R}$ leaves the topology on $\mathbb{R}\cup\{\infty\}$ ambiguous. One "natural" choice is to use the topology generated by $$\{(a, b): a,b\in\mathbb{R}\}\cup\{(a, \infty]: a\in\mathbb{R}\},$$ but it would also be consistent to take $\{\infty\}$ open, or many weirder choices as well. (By "consistent" I mean that the resulting topology yields the standard topology on the subspace $\mathbb{R}$.) So in that sense, there are really two components of your question:

- **Does the usual metric on $\mathbb{R}$ determine the topology of $\mathbb{R}\cup\{\infty\}$?** The answer to this is **no**.
- **Despite that, can we still tell whether the map $x\mapsto \infty$ is continuous?** The answer to this is **yes**: regardless of what topology we put on $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}\cup\{\infty\}$, every constant map is continuous.

Comment: I'd say the natural choice is to use the order topology.

Comment: @celtschk For that you'd first have to put a total order in $\;\Bbb R\cup\{\infty\}\;$ ...

Comment: @DonAntonio: The very *definition* of $\infty$ already gives a total order for this set: $\infty>r$ for all $r\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: @celtschk I don't understand that: in the Alexandroff compactification, $\;\infty\;$ is just a point added. For that matter it could be denoted by $\;\alpha\;$ or && . Anyway, I can't see how the order topology is "the natural" choice.

Comment: @DonAntonio: From the question, it is clear that this is about adding the two elements $\pm\infty$ to the reals, giving what is known as the [extended real number line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line). See especially the section about order and topological properties on the linked Wikipedia page.

Comment: @celtschk The last two lines is an explanation of the OP for his question, which is *not* about the extended real line. I, for one, from the beginning thought of the Alexandroff compacitification. Anyway, if the OP has problems wrapping his mind around the Alexandroff case, with the order topology he's going to have, likely, way more problems.

Comment: @DonAntonio: As I understand it, it's effectively about adding $\infty$ as largest element to the reals as "in between step" to adding both $\infty$ and $-\infty$, as that would IMHO fit best the post and the OP's apparent state of knowledge. Of course only the OP can say with certainty what he meant.

Answer (score 0):

You are introducing the set $\bar{\mathbb R}:={\mathbb R}\cup\{-\infty,\infty\}$ as codomain of functions $f:\>{\mathbb R}\to\bar{\mathbb R}$. If you want to discuss continuity of such functions you have to introduce a topology on $\bar{\mathbb R}$. The usual topology is obtained by letting the sets $\ ]M,\infty]$, $M>0$, form a neighborhood base of $\infty$, and similarly for $-\infty$. In this way $\bar{\mathbb R}$ becomes homeomorphic to the interval $[-1,1]$.

Under this setup the function $f(x):=\infty$ is admissible, and is continuous. It is a totally different matter when we are asking whether this function is integrable, even on a finite interval $[a,b]$. Of course this is not the case.